# Isn't really there encapsulation in Python

Tags: python

So today I asked if there's something like `Protected` member class in Python where many people said there's no something like lik `Public` `Protected` or `Private` . But I made the following code to test this:

```
class Vehiculo():

    def __init__(self, peso):
        self.__peso = peso
```

and from an outer class I did:

```
car = Vehiculo(10)
car.__peso = 20
```

and what it printed was still 10, so this is like `Private`, however when I changed the class variable with just one underline:

```
class Vehiculo():

        def __init__(self, peso):
            self._peso = peso
```

it printed 20 instead. Can someone clearly explain this to me? I've read a very similar post (that many consider as duplicate) but I DON'T UNDERSTAND what they say. This is exactly the `Public` `Private` behavior. And I'd like to know how to do a `Protected` behavior or if it's even possible.

Thanks and regads.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as public, private or protected in Python classes. Private methods and values are usually prefixed with an `_` underscore as a convention to hint to other developers that this shouldn't be accessed directly. However, there are no mechanisms to prevent you from simply accessing those members.

The double underscore convention (`__init__`, `__lt__`, etc) is typically used by Python itself to set specific module-level or class-level variables. These are sometimes referred to as ["magic methods"](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html).

Comment: As I mentioned, I did some test and the double underline didn't let me access that variable from other module or class unless I used a setter function....

Comment: You didn't show how you tried to print the double underscore value. Most likely you were accessing it incorrectly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's right... Maybe it has something to do with python verison? I'm using 3.5.2

Answer (score 1):

Attributes with a double underscore prefix are mangled, but they are not private. You can still do `car._Vehiculo__peso = 20`, and that will successfully set the "private" variable.

Comment: I tried it, and it didn't change

Comment: Then you did somethng different.